# Scala Yield results of calculation using foreach/for

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I wrote the following

```
val suspects  =   
tenCalls.foreach{f=>IllegalOddsCalcs.getOddsForMsisdnScala(f._2.toList)}
```

or it can be this

```
  val suspects = for (f <- tenCalls) 
  (IllegalOddsCalcs.getOddsForMsisdnScala(f._2.toList))
```

When I run the above, the suspect list is always empty, as I have not used the yield. How can I use the yield with the above to populate the suspects, or should I be using something else?

Comment: I have printed statement in the getOddsForMsisdnScala, so I know that the suspects are getting created

Answer (score 3):

`foreach` is stateful and returns `Unit`. You need to use `map` instead. Or you can add a `yield` after your `for`

```
val suspects = tenCalls.map(f=>...)
```

OR

```
val suspects = for(f <- tenCalls) yield {...}
```

Comment: Thanks Justin Pihony... I used the yield to fix the code.. so using the following worked...                                                                                            val suspects = for (f <- tenCalls) yield {IllegalOddsCalcs.getOddsForMsisdnScala(f._2.toList)}

Answer (score -1):

I guess @Justin is right. The "foreach" paradigm is defined in:

```
scala.collection.generic.FilterMonadic
```

And its return type is "Unit" (or say, "void"). And in your case, you should use map:

```
abstract def map[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That
```